# Invoke Ajax only when a particular button is clicked

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have few text fields on a page and the corresponding required field validators. I have different links and a button on the same page. Basically, I want Ajax to be activated only when I click the button .It should not be activated when I click other links.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Validation

> Validation groups allow you to organize validation controls on a page
>   as a set. Each validation group can perform validation independently
>   from other validation groups on the page.

Then in your button give for it's validation group property this group name

references

[Specifying Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Button.ValidationGroup Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup.aspx)